# starting an IntentService

Tags: android, intentservice

I have an activity "PSActivity" and an IntentServive "StalkService".  I am starting the service but the service never executes, at least according to the debugger.  The following code starts the service inside PSActivity and I am sure this is getting executed...

```
public void cbRealTime_Clicked(View v) {
    //start the StalkService
    if (cbRealTime.isChecked()) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, StalkService.class);
        i.putExtra("mystuff", "this is my stuff");
        this.startService(i);

    } else {
        //stop the service here
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the service...

```
public class StalkService extends IntentService {

    public StalkService() {
        super("StalkService");
        // must override constructor
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String data = (String) intent.getExtras().get("mystuff");
        data = data + "debug";

    }
}
```

I have a breakpoint set at data = data + "debug"; that never is hit.  It looks like onHandleIntent is never getting executed. I'm testing with the emulator.  What am I forgetting to do?
Thanks,
Gary

Comment: Is this service registered in the manifest? Do you have any messages in LogCat?

Comment: ummmm.  pp544  ^_^;;  thank you.

Comment: have you added your service in android manifest, check the simple example here http://wiki.workassis.com/android-intentservice-example/

Answer (score 0):

This was answered by CommonsWare comment.  I failed to register the service in my manifest file.
Gary